# OpenGl рисует непонятно что

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Вот содержимое моего main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>


GLuint VBO;

struct Vector3f
{
float x;
float y;
float z;

Vector3f()
{
}

Vector3f(float _x, float _y, float _z)
{
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    z = _z;
}
};

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
Vector3f Vertices[3];
Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
Vertices[2] = Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 03");

InitializeGlutCallbacks();

// Must be done after glut is initialized!
GLenum res = glewInit();
if (res != GLEW_OK) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
  return 1;
}

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

CreateVertexBuffer();

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

OpenGL не рисует ничего. Если поменять цвет в

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

то цвет фона изменится, но так же ничего нарисованно не будет.

Кроме того если в

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

заменить треугольники на точки, то будет нарисованна белая точка в центре.

В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Он рисует непонятно что, так как у вас `vao` (vertex array object) не верно использован, и криво cконфигурированы аттрибуты вершины функцией `glVertexAttribPointer`

короче, функцию

`static void CreateVertexBuffer()`

замените на

```
GLuint VBO, VAO;

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
   Vector3f Vertices[3];
   Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
   Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
   Vertices[2] = Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

   glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
   glBindVertexArray(VAO);
     glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
     glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
     glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
     glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3f), 0);
   glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

и функцию

`static void RenderSceneCB()`

на

```
static void RenderSceneCB()
{
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
     glBindVertexArray(0);

     glutSwapBuffers();
}
```